# Storing UUIDs in sqlite using Pylons and SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm working on my first Pylons project using SQLalchemy and sqlite.
I'd like to use UUIDs as the primary key for one of my tables. I found the question below and I used the code to add a custom UUID() type to SQLalchemy. (the second solution, I wasn't able to figure out how to use the suggestion by zzzeek.)

[Random ids in sqlalchemy (pylons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521686/random-ids-in-sqlalchemy-pylons)

However, when I try it out, I get ValueError('bytes is not a 16-char string')
I suspect this has to do with the fact that I'm trying to store this UUID in a sqlite VARCHAR type field.
Does anyone know what type of field I should use in sqlite that would work for these UUIDs from SQLalchemy?

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were right this just work for postgresql (db I use).
but I dive in the post you provide [Random ids in sqlalchemy (pylons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521686/random-ids-in-sqlalchemy-pylons), it really work in sqlite, just don't follow the zzzeek answer
go to the Tom Willis solutions, just some things to take in consideration I follow complete this code but change some things:
line by line:

```
#I delete follow line:
from sqlalchemy.databases.mysql import MSBinary
```

because in sqlalchemy 0.6 it's dialects.sqllite but I don't use that
I use the:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Binary
```

just change the follow line in the UUID class:

```
class UUID(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = Binary # this one!

...
...
id_column_name = "id"

def id_column():
    import uuid
    return Column(id_column_name,UUID(),primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4)


#usage:
app_uuid = Column(u'app_uuid', UUID(), primary_key=True)
```

And that works for me, good luck!

## previous answer

```
user = Table(
    'User',
    meta.metadata,
    Column('ID', UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
    Column('Name', String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
)
```

Comment: Hi @rob.alarcon,
Thanks for your input. I have almost the exact code, except for the as_uuid=True part. When I add that, it doesn't work (TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_uuid').
I think the problem is not so much in SQLalchemy, but more in what kind of field I need to define in SQLite to be able to store these UUIDs...
`class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    id = Column(UUID(), primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(Unicode(30))
    lastname = Column(Unicode(50))`

Answer (score 2):

The `sqlite` module expects to work with `unicode` data (which it encodes as UTF-8 prior to storing in the database) for text fields. You can send binary data by enclosing the value in a `buffer()` call.